# Why and How the Lion is being removed from almost all printed bibles and replaced by the Wolf in Isaiah 11:6?

Tags: isaiah

We still have imagery of the Lion and the Lamb as proof on how that verse was. How this change of the written word of God can't be satanic induced? Satan changed the word of God in the beginning when tempted Eve, he added to God words: the word "any" of the trees. There we have proof that Satan paraphrased God spoken words, inserting new "stuff" in it. Those times the word of God was not written but verbal.

It wouldn't be easier for Satan to insert or distort the written word of God? By cursing the bible using proper human granted technology, then Satan would curse the physical world as a result. The Revelation Effect is a warning from Jesus to not add/remove or twist God written word. Otherwise they will receive a curse. Is that what is happening in here? How any Christian could defend the Wolf?

Comment: 'Remove' implies *it was ever there*, which is false. You or others must have confused that verse with 65:25, which says: "The wolf and **the lamb shall feed together; the lion** and the ox shall eat straw; and dust shall be the serpent's food: they shall not hurt nor kill in all my holy mountain, saith the Lord." Also, how would Satan be able to change every copy of Isaiah in the world?

Comment: It's probably easier to remember the alliterative but mistaken 'lion and the lamb' than 'lion and the wolf,' which when you think about it makes more sense. Jesus speaks of wolves endangering the flock, e.g., not lions.

Comment: Sola Gratia: Sermons from known christian pastors/preachers (i.e. J. Vernon Mcgee and Chuck Smith) are indeed in audio record citing Isaiah 11:6 as the Lion and the Lamb.  So those pastors are then wrong and confused too?  Supernatural changes can be performed by supernatural beings, by the end of the day Jesus will not post a warning on Revelation if the bible could not be changed supernaturally.

Comment: Isaiah 11:6; 65:25 have always been difficult to quote since they're full of creatures that have various other prophetic significances. They have never changed, but they have been often misremembered.

Comment: If you've decided a worldwide corruption of the Bible has occurred, there exists no form of evidence which can dispell the notion. A sermon is only evidence that they thought a text read a certain way. Not that it does or did. Wolf corresponds to sheep in the rest of Scripture, why can't you grant fallible men have confused it rather than Satan has won over God's Word?—the latter is not necessary and the former answers the question very easily.

Comment: Is this a rant or a question?  You lost me, I confess.  Can you please reorganize your question to focus it on a single topic, so that we have a chance at getting you a good answer?

Comment: Korvin: This is a question for people to open their very old bibles and check if they really remember to be Wolf there. If this is indeed true, then it should be a rant for any pastor. We can't collectively misremember something, specially for those who read their bibles profusely and with passion, like those preachers. Do you remember wolf and lamb or lion and lamb?

Comment: @Korvin This is just another version of the Berenstain Bears phenomenon / Mandela effect.

Comment: If you want to ask a serious question about Christian doctrine and beliefs, such as "Why is the phrase "lion and the lamb" so popular when it doesn't appear in scripture," that's fine -- but this isn't a platform for rants and speculation.

Answer (score 2):

There do exist slight differences between various verses of different biblical manuscripts (though none of these have any impact of Christian doctrine).

Scholars have put much effort into determining what the content of the original copies were. This is done by analyzing old fragments and manuscripts of the Bible that have been discovered. Among the oldest are the Dead Sea Scrolls, which include a complete copy of the Book of Isaiah, dating from  356-103 BC. In verse Isaiah 11:6, this copy appears to use the Hebrew word for "wolf" (זְאֵב zeh-abe') and not the word for "lion" (אֲרִי ar-ee').

[image]
(Isaiah 11:6 is underlined in green)

The original version of the King James Version, published in 1611, seems to agree and also uses the word "wolf".

[image]

The verse Isaiah 65:25, which uses similar imagery, also uses "wolf" in both the Dead Sea Scrolls and the original King James version. On this note, it is amazing how accurate God has maintained copies of the Bible for three and half thousand years!

I don't know when or how the word "lion" become a popular rendering of these verses. Some have suggested that it's a contraction of the entire verse.

> The wolf shall dwell with the lamb, and the leopard shall lie down
>   with the young goat, and the calf and the lion and the fattened calf
>   together; and a little child shall lead them. (Isaiah 6:11)
>
> he wolf and the lamb shall graze together; the lion shall eat straw
>   like the ox, and dust shall be the serpent’s food. They shall not hurt
>   or destroy in all my holy mountain (Isaiah 65:25)

In any case, "The lion shall lay down with the lamb" version of these verses has become well known in our society, as you have noted. However, it important to remember that, as Christians, we are not the followers of any particular preacher, but rather we are followers of Christ (see 1 Corinthians 3), and that "All Scripture is breathed out by God and profitable for teaching, for reproof, for correction, and for training in righteousness, that the man of God may be complete, equipped for every good work." (2 Timothy 3:16-17)